# Exchanging large amounts of data with external devices (not wifi)

Tags: esp32

I would like to send and receive large amount of data from an external device to/from the esp32 so the later one can send/receive via wifi. I though to use the SPI as it can handle high frequency rates (documentation say stable frequency 18Mhz). The question is if it would be possible to do so? If not, what would be the best way to exchange data with external devices then?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: theoretically it is possible, however in practice it is more complicated. The spi protocol downside is that it cannot be slowed if for example you cannot process data that fast. The bottleneck in your design is the time required to receive and redirect the data via wifi. What I would recommend you to do is check how much time you require between receiving data and sending it, then you can calculate the maximum frequency you can use. Also keep in mind limitations like the amount of ram in esp32.

Comment: What connections does the external device offer?